# How to fix "If statement" from adding variables exponentially?

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I am trying to use a set of range sliders to impact each other in various ways.  My If the statement is working correctly the first time I change a value, but the second time I change a value, it is adding the entire value instead of the change.

I've tried everything I know so far on how to resolve this, but breaks and continues do not seem to be fixing the problem.

```
<form>
<Label for="sliderBarOne">Ready</Label>
<input type="range" id="sliderBarOne" min="0" max="100" step="0.01" value="0" onchange="this.form.rangeOne.value=this.value">
<input type="number" id="rangeOne" value="0" onchange="this.form.sliderBarOne.value=this.value">
<br>
<Label for="sliderBarTwo">ACW</Label>
<input type="range" id="sliderBarTwo" min="0" max="100" step="0.01" value="0" onchange="this.form.rangeTwo.value=this.value">
<input type="number" id="rangeTwo" value="0" onchange="this.form.sliderBarTwo.value=this.value">
<br>
<Label for="sliderBarThree">Extra</Label>
<input type="range" id="sliderBarThree" min="0" max="100" step="0.01" value="0" onchange="this.form.rangeThree.value=this.value">
<input type="number" id="rangeThree" value="0" onchange="this.form.sliderBarThree.value=this.value">
<br>Sum: <span id="sum">0</span>
</form>

<script>

document.getElementById("sliderBarOne").addEventListener("change", updateReady);
document.getElementById("sliderBarTwo").addEventListener("change", updateACW);
document.getElementById("sliderBarThree").addEventListener("change", updateExtra);
document.getElementById("rangeOne").addEventListener("change", updateReady);
document.getElementById("rangeTwo").addEventListener("change", updateACW);
document.getElementById("rangeThree").addEventListener("change", updateExtra);

function updateReady() {
  var readyBox = document.getElementById('sliderBarOne');
  var acwBox = document.getElementById('sliderBarTwo'); 
  var extraBox = document.getElementById('sliderBarThree');
  var readyField = document.getElementById('rangeOne');
  var acwField = document.getElementById('rangeTwo');
    if (readyBox.value < 100 || readyField.value < 100) {
      acwBox.value = 100 - parseFloat(readyBox.value);

      //Set Slider Values Into Fields
      readyField.value = readyBox.value;
      acwField.value = acwBox.value;
      extraField.value = extraBox.value;
    }
  updateSum();
}

function updateACW() {
  var readyBox = document.getElementById('sliderBarOne');
  var acwBox = document.getElementById('sliderBarTwo'); 
  var extraBox = document.getElementById('sliderBarThree');
  updateSum();
}

function updateExtra() {
  var readyBox = document.getElementById('sliderBarOne');
  var acwBox = document.getElementById('sliderBarTwo'); 
  var extraBox = document.getElementById('sliderBarThree');
  var readyField = document.getElementById('rangeOne');
  var acwField = document.getElementById('rangeTwo');
  var extraField = document.getElementById('rangeThree');
    if (extraBox.value > 0 || extraField.value > 0) {
      readyBox.value = parseFloat(readyBox.value) - parseFloat(extraBox.value);
      acwBox.value = parseFloat(acwBox.value) + parseFloat(extraBox.value);
      //Set Slider Values Into Fields
      readyField.value = readyBox.value;
      acwField.value = acwBox.value;
      extraField.value = extraBox.value;
    }
  updateSum();
}
</script>
```

The first time I enter a value into Ready, it properly subtracts that value from 100 to provide ACW.

Then, when I put a value into Extra, it accurately subtracts that value from Ready and adds to ACW.  For instance, Ready 95, ACW 5. Making Extra 1 makes Ready 94 and ACW 6.  The problem is, when I change Extra to 2, it makes Ready 92 and ACW 8 instead of Ready 93 and ACW 7.

I'm not sure how to grab the change in the value on each change.

Answer (score 0):

Because the values are changed before. You first change them by `1`, and then change them by `2`. Hence, it means the extra is `3`! Unless you reload the page to reinitialize the values to `95` and `6` and then apply extra `2`. It will give you `93` and `7`.

To solve the problem you can write an `initialize` function that initializes the values, and then call the function at the first line of the `updateExtra` function.

Comment: How can I reinitialize without wiping the values?

Comment: Sorry.  I'm still new here.  How do you check an update?  Do you mean writing an initialize function?  I'm not sure how to do that part.  I apologize.

Comment: I didn't do it how you explained, but I took the concept you talked about to find a workaround that works.  I created an initial input field, and am drawing the math from there.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

your updatesum() is not defined and your extrafield  is not defined in updateready() function

Comment: Thanks.  updatesum is related to another function that is working, so I didn't add it.   Good catch on the updateready

Answer (score 0):

OmG provided the inspiration to create an initial value field.  So, I adjusted the code as follows.  Thanks OmG!

```
function updateExtra() {
  var readyBox = document.getElementById('sliderBarOne');
  var acwBox = document.getElementById('sliderBarTwo'); 
  var extraBox = document.getElementById('sliderBarThree');
  var readyField = document.getElementById('rangeOne');
  var acwField = document.getElementById('rangeTwo');
  var extraField = document.getElementById('rangeThree');
  var initialReady = document.getElementById('initialReady');
  var initialACW = document.getElementById('initialACW');
    if (extraBox.value > 0 || extraField.value > 0) {
      readyBox.value = parseFloat(initialReady.value) - parseFloat(extraBox.value);
      acwBox.value = parseFloat(initialACW.value) + parseFloat(extraBox.value);
      //Set Slider Values Into Fields
      readyField.value = readyBox.value;
      acwField.value = acwBox.value;
      extraField.value = extraBox.value;
    }
  updateSum();
}
```